# É possível concatenar um seletor jQuery com uma variável?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código dentro de uma função javascript que esta dentro de uma pagina .php:

```
if (indice_da_aba == -1)
{
   window.alert('não existe ABAS AINDA');
}
else                    
if (indice_da_aba == 0)
{
   $('a[href="#tab_00"]').tab('show');
}
else
if (indice_da_aba == 1)
{
   $('a[href="#tab_01"]').tab('show');
}
else
if (indice_da_aba == 2)
{
   $('a[href="#tab_02"]').tab('show');
}
```

Como podem ver são muitos `if`s.

Gostaria de saber se é possível escrever um `if` da seguinte forma:

```
if (indice_da_aba == -1)
{
   window.alert('não existe ABAS AINDA');
}
else                    
{
   $('a[href="#tab_0+indice_da_aba+"]').tab('show');
}
```

Do modo que escrevi não funciona.  Teria um modo certo de escrever (concatenar) essa linha ou não é possível?

Comment: Não conseguiria usar `$('a[href="#tab_0'+indice_da_aba+'"]')`? O que me parece que está te faltando é o fecha e abre parentese para concatenar a variavel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, usando o operador de concatenação (`+`).

```
$('a[href="#tab_0' + indice_da_aba + '"]').tab('show');
```

Só que pra isso, você precisa ter um valor em cada lado do operador. No código mostrado, você até usou os `+`, porém esqueceu de fechar as aspas para "fechar" a string.

Também pode fazer de uma forma mais moderna, usando [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```
$(`a[href="#tab_0${indice_da_aba}"]`).tab('show');
```

Note que esta última forma pode não funcionar em alguns browsers.

Veja funcionando:

```js
const indice_da_aba = 123;

console.log('a[href="#tab_0' + indice_da_aba + '"]');
console.log(`a[href="#tab_0${indice_da_aba}"]`);
```

Answer (score 4):

Você apenas esqueceu as `aspas simples` antes e depois do `+`

```js
if (indice_da_aba == -1){
   window.alert('não existe ABAS AINDA');
}else{
   $('a[href="#tab_0'+indice_da_aba+'"]').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: Retiro meu negativo. Agora está explicado :P.

Comment: @GustavoCinque Desculpa, eu tinha postado antes de explicar rs, ai editei. Obrigado :D

Comment: Antes e depois do `+`.

Comment: @DvD Exatamente, editei a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: @Rafael Augusto boa tarde :).  Depois que o LINQ postou a resposta e vi que tinha esquecido a aspa simples me senti um pastel sem nada dentro... :).  Obrigado pela sua atenção. Marquei a resposta do LINQ como aceita pois do outro modo que ele mostrou não conhecia :).  Abraços e obrigado pela sua atenção :)